# Sometimes the consumer group for a unique id does gets created and the consumer is stuck without partitions

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

The configuration for the Consumer is as below. Sometimes for a unique id, the consumer group is not created at all. I am trying to consume the messages as per the application name. Even the script for the consumer group does not show that particular consumer group in the list. for eg the group id given application8 is not created at all I receive in logs is as below.

2019-11-14 14:09:27,719 INFO  - Kafka version: 2.3.1
2019-11-14 14:09:27,719 INFO  - Kafka commitId: 18a913733fb71c01
2019-11-14 14:09:27,719 INFO  - Kafka startTimeMs: 1573720767718
2019-11-14 14:09:27,720 INFO  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=Application8] Subscribed to topic(s): config
2019-11-14 14:09:27,955 INFO  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=Application8] Cluster ID: h1TJ0oMkQYqO0z8ftlIzpA

```
public static void KafkaServerStart() throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.134:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "Application8");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
    props.put("partition.assignment.strategy", "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("heartbeat.interval.ms", "3000");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "9000");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset","latest");

    consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("config"), new RebalanceConfigListener());
    final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
    // Registering a shutdown hook so we can exit cleanly
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Starting exit...");
            // KafkaConsumers.consumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumers.currentOffsets);
            // Note that shutdownhook runs in a separate thread, so the only thing we can
            // safely do to a consumer is wake it up
            consumer.wakeup();
            try {
                mainThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    try {
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
            boolean commit = false;
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record : records) {
                /**
                 * Code for committing the offset on every iteration. Start.
                 */

                if (!commit)
                    commit = true;

                /**
                 * Code for committing the offset on every iteration. End.
                 */
                // LiveDa.processData(record.key(), record.value(), record.offset(),
                // record.partition());
                Reinit.reInitMethod(new String(record.value()));

                /*
                 * System.out.println("Key of the data " + record.key() + "  ,values " + new
                 * String(record.value()) + " ,offset is " + record.offset() +
                 * " ,Partition ID  " + record.partition());
                 */
                /**
                 * Code for committing the offset on every iteration. Start.
                 */

                currentOffsets.put(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()),
                        new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset() + 1, "no metadata"));

                /**
                 * Code for committing the offset on every iteration. End.
                 */
            }
            /**
             * Code for committing the offset on every iteration. Start.
             */

            if (commit)
                consumer.commitAsync(currentOffsets, null);

            /**
             * Code for committing the offset on every iteration. End.
             */
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // write logic on shutdown.
        System.out.println("EXITING KAFKA");
        /**
         * Code for committing the offset on every iteration. Start.
         */
        consumer.commitSync(currentOffsets);
        /**
         * Code for committing the offset on every iteration. End.
         */
        consumer.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        KafkaConfigConsumer.KafkaServerStart();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        KafkaConfigConsumer.KafkaServerStart();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        SystemLogger.error(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: How many partition and how many consumer instances  for unique consumer group u have?

Comment: @sun007 I Resolved the issue it was problem with the __consumer_offset topic, One of the kafka node was down and the partitions associated with that node were leaderless, so after resetting the topic the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Resolved the issue it was problem with the __consumer_offset topic, One of the kafka node was down and the partitions associated with that node were leaderless, so after resetting the topic the issue got resolved.